# How to determine an object belong to a specific class

Tags: java, oop, data-structures

Here is my class definitions of interface Icontestant:

```
   interface IContestant {  
}

class TennisPlayer implements IContestant {
  String name;
  int ranking;

  TennisPlayer (String name, Integer ranking){
    this.name = name;
    this.ranking = ranking;
  }
}

class NotYetKnown  implements IContestant {

  NotYetKnown (){
  }
}
```

Here is my definition of classes MatchData:

```
    class MatchData {
  IContestant side1;
  IContestant side2;
  IContestant winner;
  IScore score;


  MatchData (IContestant side1, IContestant side2, IContestant winner, IScore score){
    this.side1 = side1;
    this.side2 = side2;
    this.winner = winner;
    this.score = score;
  }      
}
```

Here is my definition of ITournament

```
interface ITournament {
  boolean winnerPlayed ();
}

class InitMatch implements ITournament {
  MatchData matchData;  

  InitMatch (MatchData matchData){
    this.matchData = matchData;
  }

 public boolean winnerPlayed (){
    if ((this.matchData.winner == this.matchData.side1)||(this.matchData.winner == this.matchData.side2)){
        return true;
      }
      else
        return false;
    }
    else 
      return true;
  }

}
```

Now I need to add a condition to `winnerPlayed ()` to check if the winner is unknown first. If it is unknown, then we can just return true before checking if winner is either side1 or side2. However, I am having hard time to get this condition correct.
I am so confused in this case what to use to compare with `this.matchData.winner`. I get it that `this.matchData.side1` is a `TennisPlayer`, `this.matchData.side2` is another `TennisPlayer`, so we are comparing if `this.matchData.winner` is a `TennisPlayer` of side1 or side2. But when it comes to unknown, I start to get confused.
If you could explain data structure and objects here that would be great.

Thank you.

Also, the example of TennisPlayer and Unknown looks like this:

```
  TennisPlayer tennisPlayer1 = new TennisPlayer("Andre Agassi", 7);
  TennisPlayer tennisPlayer2 = new TennisPlayer ("Pat", 4);
  NotYetKnown unknown = new NotYetKnown();
  MatchData matchTennis2 = new MatchData (tennisPlayer1, tennisPlayer2, notYetKnown, tennisScore3 );
  InitMatch initTennis1 = new InitMatch (matchTennis1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A game has two players so winner must be either side1 or side2 if the game has been played or null if the game hasn’t been played yet. Any other option would mean that you have inconsistent data.

*Edit*

If for some reason winner can’t be null and is always set to a NotKnownYet object then could use instanceof to check for this

```
if winner instanceof NotYetKnown {...
```

Comment: So when i add condition: if (this.matchData.winner != ***){} to check if winner is unknown, what would be ***?

Comment: *** = null. This is the only thing that makes sense

Comment: Then you need to define what unknown is.

Comment: I tried to run it with *** = null with my examples which I added to the original question. I simply asked to return true if matchData.winner == null. However, it returns false

Comment: I did edit my answer earlier, given your last edit wouldn't instanceof work?

Comment: Hi, I tried instanceof. It works! In this case since class NotYetKnown is empty so this is the only way to do it?

Comment: That doesn’t make sense, instanceof will work no matter if the class is empty or not.

Comment: it works. I was asking if it is true that there is no other way to check it since NotYetKnown is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should give blank string as a name for an unknown player. Then have a method to retrieve players names and if the name that is retrieve is an empty string you know the player is unknown. I know this might not be exactly the solution your probably looking for but it's probably easier way of going about it.

Comment: I think your answer is a good work around. But I think I have some knowledge gap of oop and data structure from the problem I encounter. So I would like to see if there is some answer can help me think through. Thank you!

Comment: What output is it giving you that it shouldn't be would probably help me help you.

Comment: Because what im thinking is that your comparing the references to those tennis player / notyetknown objects instead of some value given to them to determine whether they are known or not which might be the issue because it should always return true because of this

Comment: so I updated my original question with proper examples given. To check if this.matchData.winner is NotYetKnown, instead of TennisPlayer, I don't even really know what should I put to replace *** here:  if (this.matchData.winner != ***){}

Comment: In the case where notyetknown is used for the this.match.winner your always going to get false from winnerplayed unless unknown gets set with a reference to one of your tennis players. I dont think you should ever need winnerplayed or notyetknown logically  because your winner wont be unknown after the match, youll know who is playing in the match, and the winner out of two people should have always played.

Comment: So what if we replace unknown class with soccer team class with string country, how do we check if winner/player/game is soccer or 
 tennis? someone mentioned using instanceof, I wonder if this is the only way to check